# History of the relation between $p$-adic measures and power series

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, p-adic-analysis, iwasawa-theory

In 1964, Kubota and Leopoldt defined the $p$-adic $L$-function by means of some $p$-adic sums (now called the Volkenborn integral which is a $p$-adic distribution). Later, Mazur (in his secret Bourbaki report, now available is his web page) developed the theory of $p$-adic measures to give another definition of this function, and also, in 1969, Iwasawa defined the same function by means of some power series (in connection with cyclotomic fields). Now it is known that both points of view are "isomorphic".

My question is: **who was the first mathematician to realize that $p$-adic measures and power series with $p$-adic integer coefficientes were actually the same?**

(Maybe, the first book to treat this relation in detail was Lang's "Cyclotomic Fields".)

Comment: If you relax the condition on $p$-adic measures to be $\mathbf Q_p$-valued instead of $\mathbf Z_p$-valued and the condition on power series coefficients to be bounded in $\mathbf Q_p$ instead of being in $\mathbf Z_p$ (i.e., bounded by $1$) then see *Mesures $p$-adiques* by Amice from 1965. This paper is available online from  NUMDAM.

Comment: Dear @KConrad: As always, thank you very much for the reference. I'll take a look a that paper. For the interested reader, the link is the following: http://www.numdam.org/item/SDPP_1964-1965__6_2_A7_0

Comment: @KConrad After searching a while, Amice's paper is probably the first to treat the relation between distributions (dual spaces) and power series. Please post your comment as an answer to accept it. Thanks again.